# Update Android sdk make error

Tags: android

I updated my android sdk, but when I create a new application I get new option on that I've never seen before.
[image]

what this mean .
I give a name to this parent activity , but when I run the application I get this error

```
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

The full console output

```
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] ------------------------------
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Android Launch!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Performing sync
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Androidvirtual'
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Androidvirtual'
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] ------------------------------
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Android Launch!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Performing sync
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Androidvirtual'
[2012-08-13 13:54:35 - GG] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Androidvirtual'
[2012-08-13 13:54:48 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-08-13 13:54:50 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: /home/belkacem/.android/avd/Androidvirtual.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-08-13 13:54:50 - GG] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-08-13 13:54:50 - GG] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-13 13:54:51 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-08-13 13:54:51 - GG] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2012-08-13 13:54:51 - GG] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-13 13:55:18 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-08-13 13:55:18 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-08-13 13:55:18 - GG] emulator-5556 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
[2012-08-13 13:55:20 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-08-13 13:55:20 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-08-13 13:55:20 - GG] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.java"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="d" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
No Launcher activity found!
```

Your manifest file must have one activity as app launcher...

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>    

</activity>
```

Comment: but in before update android sdk , i run the application without add any activity as app launcher

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a launching activity.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.java"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in your activity tag, this will take care of issue I guess.

Comment: but in before update android sdk , i run the application without add any activity as app launcher